# Bool method keeps returning false

Tags: c#, methods, switch-statement, boolean

So this code checks to make sure the user has entered a proper math operator in my calculator, but no matter what I seem to do the code ALWAYS gives me false and it's driving me nuts.

```
if (IsOperator(txtOperator.ToString(), "Operator")




        public bool IsOperator(string textBox, string name)
        {
            switch (textBox)
            {
                case "*":
                    return true;
                case "x":
                    return true;
                case "/":
                    return true;
                case "+":
                    return true;
                case "-":
                    return true;
            }
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a valid math operator.", "Entry Error");
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: Use a debugger. What is the value of the `textBox` parameter?

Comment: You can debug your code to find the issue very easily. put the return value of `IsOperator(txtOperator.ToString(), "Operator")` call into a variable and inspect it in the debug mode. you will be able to see if the value is what you expect or not.

Comment: Side point: you can combine the `case` statements by removing `return true;` except for the last one

Comment: `textBox.ToString()` will most likely return the type name like `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` or `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`.
You very likely want `IsOperator(txtOperator.Text`... which will provide the text entered by the user...

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `txtOperator.Text` instead of `txtOperator.ToString()` in the call to `IsOperator`,  assuming `txtOperator` is a TextBox.

Have you already debugged the app and inspected the value?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to pass in the the **Text** property of that textbox...

```
   if (IsOperator(txtOperator.Text, "Operator")) { ...
```

The method itself could be optimized to sth like:

```
    public bool IsOperator(string textEntered, string name)
    {
        switch (textEntered?.Trim())
        {
            case "*":
            case "x":
            case "/":
            case "+":
            case "-":
                return true;

            default:
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a valid math operator", "Entry Error");
                return false;

        }
    }
```